# Executar comandos do Rails no terminal do Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, terminal, console

Estou aprendendo Ruby através de um curso da Alura e tenho uma dúvida.

Toda vez que quero executar um comando do rails, como por exemplo *startar* o servidor com o comando `rails server` ocorre o seguinte erro :

> bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby2.3: interpretador inválido:
>   Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

Para resolver isto, toda vez que o terminal é aberto eu executo o comando abaixo:
source `/home/wagner/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

**A minha dúvida é:** Existe alguma forma de automatizar a execução do comando source `/home/wagner/.rvm/scripts/rvm`? Está ficando chato ter que executá-lo toda vez que o terminal é aberto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duas coisas podem ser feitas:

Adicionar em seu aquivo `~/.profile` ou `~/.bashrc`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Ou a maneira mais recomendada, por exemplo no `Gnome Terminal`:

(PS: Sua distribuição parece estar em **pt-br**, vou passar os caminhos em **en**, não deve ser difícil achar o caminho correspondente)

> Edit -> Profiles Preferences -> Title and Command

Ai você marca a opção:

```
"Run command as login shell"
```

E fecha e reabre novamente o gnome-terminal.

Fonte: [Integrating RVM with gnome-terminal](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal)<sup>(en)</sup>

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.