# Terminal Xfce não reconhece comandos ruby e rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

Olá, ao tentar executar comandos ruby ou rails no terminal do linux Manjaro ocorre erro informando que o comando não é reconhecido.
 Tentei realizar o mesmo procedimento que utilizei para o Ubuntu, porém não deu certo. Alguém tem alguma dica ?

[Executar comandos do Rails no terminal do Ubuntu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135435/executar-comandos-do-rails-no-terminal-do-ubuntu)

Comment: Qual o retorno? E qual o comando?

Comment: comando: rails new app teste -> comando para criar um projeto
retorno: bash: rails: comando não encontrado

Comment: Muito bem. Coloque essa informação na pergunta para ficar mais fácil para os outros saberem disso.

Comment: Outra dúvida : como está sua variável `$PATH`?

Comment: este é o resultado do echo $PATH
usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Comment: Você colocou o `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` dentro do seu .bashrc? Porque esse caminho não tá vindo nesse print que tu fez...

Comment: Consegui resolver o meu problema seguindo este tutorial http://lvasquez.github.io/2014/08/10/Install-Ruby-on-Rails-Manjaro/
Muito obrigado pela atenção.